# RAID0 will not assemble on boot, not able to assemble manually

Tags: boot, raid, mdadm

our lab's RAID0 array has seemingly stopped working. The system knows there are drives there, but I haven't been able to assemble them no matter what I try googling around in these forums. I've provided below some of the basic things that seem to get asked, but can provide more. I'm not super well-versed in the particulars of technical computer things, but I can follow commands pretty well.

```
~$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
mdadm: Unknown keyword /dev/md0:
/dev/md0:
    Version : 1.2
 Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 13
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

      State : inactive

       Name : mhara-BlackServer:0  (local to host mhara-BlackServer)
       UUID : 5643be60:fe02d346:c038cc99:393231f9
     Events : 20279

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

   -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
   -       8      208        -        /dev/sdn
   -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
   -       8      176        -        /dev/sdl
   -       8      144        -        /dev/sdj
   -       8      112        -        /dev/sdh
   -       8       80        -        /dev/sdf
   -       8      224        -        /dev/sdo
   -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
   -       8      192        -        /dev/sdm
   -       8      160        -        /dev/sdk
   -       8      128        -        /dev/sdi
   -       8       96        -        /dev/sdg
```

and

```
~$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdj[8](S) sdk[9](S) sdo[13](S) sdn[12](S) sdi[10](S) sdl[7](S) sdm[11](S) sdc[0](S) sdg[5](S) sdd[2](S) sdh[6](S) sde[3](S) sdf[4](S)
      50789537656 blocks super 1.2
```

unused devices:

One thing that I've noticed is there seems to be some confusion between whether the array is /dev/md0 or /dev/md/0

e.g.

```
~$ sudo mdadm -E --scan
mdadm: Unknown keyword /dev/md0:
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=5643be60:fe02d346:c038cc99:393231f9 name=mhara-BlackServer:0
   spares=1
```

Any help is appreciated. I want to get this thing up and running, hopefully with data intact, for the lab.

**Edit 1:**

```
content of mdadm.conf:

# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Tue, 11 Apr 2017 15:31:46 -0500
# by mkconf $Id$
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=5643be60:fe02d346:c038cc99:393231f9
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 13
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

      State : inactive

       Name : mhara-BlackServer:0  (local to host mhara-BlackServer)
       UUID : 5643be60:fe02d346:c038cc99:393231f9
     Events : 20279

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

   -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
   -       8      208        -        /dev/sdn
   -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
   -       8      176        -        /dev/sdl
   -       8      144        -        /dev/sdj
   -       8      112        -        /dev/sdh
   -       8       80        -        /dev/sdf
   -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
   -       8      192        -        /dev/sdm
   -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
   -       8      160        -        /dev/sdk
   -       8      128        -        /dev/sdi
   -       8       96        -        /dev/sdg
```

I previously had the output of mdadm -E --scan appended onto the end of the .conf file, but in trying to assemble it I had an error that there were two arrays named md0 or something like that, so I removed it.

**Edit 2:**

I just found out--from someone who knows a bit more about this than me, but who is not available to actually help--that the RAID was not setup with mdadm, and was probably setup as a hardware RAID(?). Any thoughts about how to determine how this was setup through the terminal? Any ideas where I should start? My googling thus far has been far less fruitful. Below is the sum of the info I have so far:

> It's a full RAID 6, meaning that you're using 12 disks actively and you have 2 remaining disks to swap in incase one of the other disks break
>   The two swap disks were the last disks in the array, 12, and 13
>   But I would have to physicially look at the computer or the notes to figure out exactly which one is which

Comment: Can you also post your `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file please? I'm wondering if there's a syntax error in it

Comment: Added that info to the OP. To my inexperienced eye, I note that there is a difference between md/0 and md0. I had tried a fix found on another thread suggesting that the output of mdadm --examine --scan >> into the .conf file, but that didn't seem to help things, so I took it back out.

Comment: I'm not a RAID expert but it looks to me like everything after the `ARRAY` line in your `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file shouldn't be there (or perhaps should be commented out, if it was placed there for reference). I don't know if that will have any effect of the working of the array, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: I commented everything other than the ARRAY line out. There doesn't seem to be any resulting change that I can find, despite trying to assemble the array.